# MSACCESS - How to create a custom property for a control

Tags: ms-access, properties, controls, customization

There is a way to create a public custom property for a control, a textbox for instance?
I just want to add a border color to a textbox like this:

```
public property Empty(ValX as Boolean)

if ValX = true then
 Screen.ActiveControl.BorderWidth = 10
 Screen.ActiveControl.BorderColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
else
 Screen.ActiveControl.BorderWidth = 0
 Screen.ActiveControl.BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
end if

end property
```

so i can use it like this:

```
text1.Empty=true
```

This is just an example of what i need..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can' overload or create your own control by inheriting from a base control.

The best you can get/do?

This would work:

```
Public Sub MyEmpty(c As Control, Highlight As Boolean)

  If Highlight Then
     c.BorderWidth = 6
     c.BorderColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  Else
     c.BorderWith = 1
     c.BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End If

End Sub
```

Thus , in form code? You would go like this:

```
MyEmpty Text1, True
```

As a FYI?
the border width is 0 to 6 allowed values.
But the color as above should work just fine.

So, not a lot of code, and not a lot of typing - but a wee bit more then if you could have created a custom property of a control - but it not a option. Above should work ok, and you don't have to rely on screen.active as a result.